# Is there a way to have a reference term in addition to a label with Doccano?

Tags: doccano

Hi I would like to know if we can have something like the following example on Doccano:

So let's say that we have a sentence like this : "MS is an IT company". I want to label some words in this sentence, for example MS (Microsoft). MS should be labelled as a Company (so imagine that I have an entity named Company) but I also want to say that MS stands for Microsoft.

Is there a way to do that with Doccano?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doccano supports

- `Sequence Labelling` good for Named Entity Recognition (NER)
- `Text Classification` good e.g. for Sentiment Analysis
- `Sequence To Sequence` good for Machine Translation

What you're describing sounds a little like Entity Linking.
You can see from [Doccano's roadmap in its docs](https://github.com/doccano/doccano/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md#annotation) that Entity Linking is part of the plans, but not yet available.

For now, I suggest to frame this as a NER problem, and to have different entities for `MS (Microsoft)` and `MS (other)`. If you have too many entities to choose from, the labelling could become complicated, but then you could break up the dataset in smaller entity-focussed datasets. For example, you could get only documents with MS in them and label the mentions as one of the few synonyms.